# Is it possible to configure bash to autocomplete with one tab like zsh?

Tags: bash, autocomplete

As most people here know, when using bash at the command prompt if you partially type a file name a command or an option to a command etc, bash will complete the word if there is exactly one match.
When there is more than one match, you need to hit `<Tab>` twice and bash will generate a list of possible matches.
I would like to configure bash to simply provide those options on the first `<Tab>`.
Is this possible without writing a script? i.e. a shell option?

`man bash` has a section "programmable completion" but I couldn't make out if there is an option to enable "single tab completion".

Comment: And... the opposite question [Is it possible to configure zsh to not autocomplete with one tab like bash](https://serverfault.com/questions/109207/how-do-i-make-zsh-completion-act-more-like-bash-completion) (which is what I wanted :)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Put this in your `~/.inputrc`:

```
set show-all-if-ambiguous on
```

For additional credit, add:

```
set completion-ignore-case on
```

All of the options are in the [GNU manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Readline-Init-File-Syntax.html#Readline-Init-File-Syntax)...

Comment: Heads up: putting this in your `~/.bash_profile` won't work. It has to go in your `~/.inputrc`

Comment: No kidding... That's why I specified placing it there.

Answer (score 14):

I do not have enough reputation to comment, but I would add to jasonwryans answers  that it can be added to `.bash_profile` or `.bashrc` by writing them as:

```
bind 'set show-all-if-ambiguous on'
bind 'set completion-ignore-case on'
```

I case anybody else finds this question as I did.